# Perl does not print properly the last line

Tags: regex, perl, file

I have a large file like this:

```
scaffold_58 Cufflinks   exon    753 993 .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G781015";transcript_id "GRMZM6G781015_T03";tss_id "TSS125032"
scaffold_58 Cufflinks   exon    753 1642    .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G781015";transcript_id "GRMZM6G781015_T02";tss_id "TSS125032"
scaffold_58 Cufflinks   exon    753 801 .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G781015";transcript_id "GRMZM6G781015_T01";tss_id "TSS125032"
scaffold_58 Cufflinks   exon    871 993 .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G781015";transcript_id "GRMZM6G781015_T01";tss_id "TSS125032"
```

The following code is meant to change the gene_id using regex..

```
use warnings;
open $final, ">", "./newassembly.gtf";
open NEWREF3, "<", $ARGV[0];
while ($line = <NEWREF3>) {
    if ($line =~ /gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*_[oO])([_.][0-9]*)";/) {
        $genename = $1; $ext = $2;
        $allname = $genename.$ext;
        if (!defined $hash_o_count{$genename}{$allname}) {
            $num = keys %{$hash_o_count{$genename}};
            $hash_o_count{$genename}{$allname} = $num + 1;
        }
        $num = keys %{$hash_o_count{$genename}};
        $line =~ s/gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*_[oO])([_.])[0-9]*";/gene_id "$1$2$hash_o_count{$genename}{$allname}";/g;
        print $final $line;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*_[xX])([_.][0-9]*)";/) {
        $genename = $1; $ext = $2;
        $allname = $genename.$ext;
        if (!defined $hash_x_count{$genename}{$allname}) {
            $num = keys %{$hash_x_count{$genename}};
            $hash_x_count{$genename}{$allname} = $num + 1;
        }
        $num = keys %{$hash_x_count{$genename}};
        $line =~ s/gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*_[xX])([_.])[0-9]*";/gene_id "$1$2$hash_x_count{$genename}{$allname}";/g;
        print $final $line;
    }
    else {
        print $final $line;
    }
}
close NEWREF3;
```

However, the output of this code gives a truncated line at the end of the file... The last line should go though the last else of the code. Doing a `head` of the output file...

```
scaffold_58 Cufflinks   exon    1153    1642    .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G781015";transcript_id "GRMZM6G781015_T01";tss_id "TSS125032"
scaffold_6  Cufflinks   exon    1   289 .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G441368";transcript_id "GRMZM6G441368_T01";tss_id "TSS125033"
scaffold_6  Cufflinks   exon    517 591 .   +   .   gene_id "GRMZM6G441368";transcript_id "GRMZM6G441368_T01";tss_id "TSS125033"
scaffold_6  Cufflinks   exon    683 905 computer@computer:/home...
```

Why is this and how to avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script, especially if you are asking for help with it. It is a simple measure that can reveal many straightforward errors that you may otherwise waste a lot of time searching for

Comment: You are not providing sample of your data that matches any of the cases in your regular expressions, so those four lines go to the `else` block. Also, you are not providing a sample of the line that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to close your file `./newassembly.gtf`. It is always a good practise to close files.

For doing it, it is as simple as:
`close $file;` after `close NEWREF3;`